Next 15 with Sanity CMS, I can't cache my datas
I'm currently in the process of migrating from Next.js 14 to Next.js 15 and encountered an issue related to caching when using the fetch function to retrieve data from Sanity. In Next.js 14, I was able to cache my data effectively, but this is not working as expected in Next.js 15, which has default caching mechanisms (No cache by default).
Here's the relevant code:
client.ts
import { createClient } from 'next-sanity';
import { apiVersion, dataset, projectId } from '../env';

const client = createClient({
  projectId,
  dataset,
  apiVersion,
  useCdn: true,
});

export default client;

sanity-query.ts
export async function getExperiences(language: string) {
  return client.fetch(
    groq`*[_type == "experience" && language == $language] | order(endDate desc){
      name,
      company,
      "logo": logo.asset->url,
      url,
      description,
      city,
      province,
      startDate,
      endDate
    }`,
    { language }
  );
}

export async function getSkills() {
  return client.fetch(
    groq`*[_type == "skill"] | order(_createdAt desc){
      localizedName,
      skills[]{
        name,
        "logo": logo.asset->url,
        "darklogo": darklogo.asset->url,
        url
      }
    }`
  );
}

Skills.ts
import { getSkills } from "@/sanity/sanity-query";
import { SkillsType } from "@/types";

const CodingSkills = async () => {
  const skills: SkillsType[] = await getSkills();
  
  return (
    <>
      <Skills codingSkills={skills} />
    </>
  );
};

export default CodingSkills;

In Next.js 15, it seems that the new caching behavior doesn't automatically apply to external data sources when using custom fetch functions like the ones above. How can I adapt my existing code to Next.js 15 to cache my data when fetching from Sanity function?
Any solutions would be appreciated!
